# Terminal does not launch after software update

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, upgrade, gnome-terminator

After doing a software update last night, I cannot launch my terminal.

I have installed [terminator](https://gnometerminator.blogspot.com/p/introduction.html) which I have used on other machines, but want to get terminal back to working form.

**I have found some proposed solutions:**

https://askubuntu.com/questions/114856/terminal-does-not-start-on-remote-desktop-how-to-fix-it

https://askubuntu.com/questions/613582/terminal-wont-launch-after-upgrading

I would prefer to get things back to a state where they work, but would like to avoid any potential unintended new and potentially worse errors.

What info may I provide to help get my terminal back in full force?

```
$ cat /etc/os-release `
```

Yields:

```
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="18.04.2 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS"
VERSION_ID="18.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=bionic
UBUNTU_CODENAME=bionic
```

When I try to launch `gnome-terminal` from terminator I get:

```
(base) user@userMS-7A37:~$ gnome-terminal
# Error constructing proxy for org.gnome.Terminal:/org/gnome/Terminal/Factory0: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.gnome.Terminal: Timeout was reached
```

When I do `sudo edit /etc/default/locale` I see:

```
#  File generated by update-locale
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
```

Comment: To offer any kind of help, we need specific information on what is not working, error messages, log outputs, etc. Is the default terminal-emulator working? Can you access the virtual-consoles? Can you connect via SSH?

Comment: So ... `terminator` works, but `gnome-terminal` doesn't? And should we conclude (from the first link) that you are using a Remote Desktop (VNC) connection?

Comment: @0xSheepdog This is a local machine. When click "terminal" in my favorites, it does not launch. I also could not open my files explorer, i had to launch nautilus via a command interface. I do not recall the interface name, but it was a small launch box that  I opened via a shortcut.

Comment: @steeldriver This is a local machine. Terminator works and was installed AFTER the error started.

Comment: @jasonm so what happens if you attempt to start the default terminal emulator (`gnome-terminal`) from the `terminator` command line?

Comment: @steeldriver I updated the question. It does not launch.

Comment: @steeldriver any thoughts?

Comment: @jasonm sorry - I don't know any more than you do